# Show that the diagonal in $[0,1]\times [0,1$ is in $\mathcal B_\{[0,1]\}\times\mathcal B_{[0,1]}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove that $$D=\{(x,x):x\in[0,1]\}\subset [0,1]\times [0,1]\in \mathcal B_{[0,1]}\times\mathcal B_{[0,1]}$$

This problem is somewhat related to a problem in Folland, problem 2.46. I thought about taking sections of $D$, but not exactly sure how to proceed. I would love to get some help.

Comment: Did you mean ${\cal{B}}_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}$ ?

Comment: Hint: note that $D$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Comment: I meant the product sigma algebra of $\mathcal B_{[0,1]}$. I'm not sure how $D$ being closed relates to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As observed in the comments it is enough to show that $\mathcal B ([0,1]\times [0,1])$ is contained in $(\mathcal B ([0,1])\times (\mathcal B [0,1])$. For this it is enough to show that any open set in $\mathbb R^{2}$ is contained in $(\mathcal B ([0,1])\times (\mathcal B [0,1])$. Since $\mathbb R^{2}$ is second countable any open set in it can be expressed as a  countable union of sets of the type $U\times V$ where $U$ and $V$ are open in $\mathbb R$. Obviously, $U\times V$ is in $\mathcal B ([0,1]\times \mathcal B [0,1])$ so we are done.

Comment: thank you for your answer, though I'm having a hard time understanding what it means. Could you elaborate a bit more? I'm a bit lost on following your argument here.

Comment: @pilotmath $D$ is closed in $\mathbb R^{2}$ so it is a Borel set there. The question is whether any Borel set in $\mathbb R^{2}$ belongs the the product $\mathcal B \times \mathcal B$ where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel sigma field of $\mathbb R$. This is true and it requires a topological argument. That is what I have given.

Comment: Ah! I see now. One last thing, why is $D$ closed? I'm not sure why it should be closed in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @pilotmath If $(x_n,x_n) \to (a,b)$ the $x_n \to a$ and $x_n \to b$ so $a=b$. Hence $(a,b) \in D$.

Comment: Also, I know that $\mathcal B_{\mathbb R^2}=\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\times\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, but is the same true if I replace $\mathbb R$ with [0,1]?

Comment: @pilotmath There is hardly any difference between the two. If you already know that $\mathcal B_{\mathbb R^{2}}=\mathcal B_{\mathbb R} \times \mathcal B_{\mathbb R}$ then my answer could have been much shorter!.

Comment: Yes I realized that! I had forgotten that I had that fact in hand :(. The problem reduces down to showing that $D$ is borel and we're done, right?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have a similar problem to this at here, could you take a look? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987764/is-this-set-borel-measurable-and-what-is-its-m2-measure